# Transfert d'adresse BTC Segwit vers adresse BTC non segwit

Tags: segregated-witness

Bonjour, je viens de faire un transfert de BTC segwits vers une adresse BTC non segwit, pensez vous que cela pose un problèmes ???

Answer (score 0):

Non, tout va bien ! C'est le même réseau « Bitcoin ».

---

Nope, all is fine ! They're both part of the same network.